# Is it possible to use mozilla's rr with gdb multi-window?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have started using mozilla's [`rr`](http://rr-project.org/) (timetravelling debugger, github [here](https://github.com/mozilla/rr)) on the command line for debugging c++ code.

In emacs I can start it with `gud-gdb` and writing `rr replay` (as mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Debugger-Operation.html#Debugger-Operation) or [here](https://github.com/mozilla/rr/issues/1484)).

I cannot start it with `gdb` followed by `rr replay`, which is how I usually start gdb in order to work in gdb many-window-mode. (which I have enabled as a setting).

When I try and start it that way I get these error messages to start off with:

```
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f53bd89a6b0 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(rr) Undefined command: "1-inferior-tty-set".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "2-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "3-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "4-enable-pretty-printing".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "5-file-list-exec-source-files".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "6-file-list-exec-source-file".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "7-gdb-show".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "8-stack-info-frame".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "9-thread-info".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "10-break-list".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "11-thread-info".  Try "help".
(rr) Undefined command: "12-break-list".  Try "help".
```

followed by this error message when I try and run anything from within the  gdb session:

```
(rr) continue
Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec".  Try "help".
(rr) run
Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec".  Try "help".
(rr) break
Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec".  Try "help".
(rr)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to run rr with emacs many-window-mode?

Comment: Timetravelling debugger? That sounds so cool!

Comment: It is quite cool. You can run a full application until it crashes with rr tracing the execution. Then run it in gdb until it crashes, set a breakpoint at a function where you think it went wrong and reverse continue and then you're at the last time the function was called before you crashed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR wrap gdb in a script that has been put in your path like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
gdb -i=mi "$@"
```

then call it with

```
M-x gdb
rr replay -d name_of_script_i_just_created
```

If that doesn't work either address the error message in rr to stop it complaining, or patch `gdb.el` as mentioned below. Long version below.

Alright, I figured it out. It does, (currently) require a bit of a patch to `gdb.el` and requires an extra bash file.

rr is able to specify the debugger it uses with `-d` so first you create a wrapped gdb with `-i=mi` like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
gdb -i=mi "$@"
```

which we have called something like gdb-rr-emacs (and which we have added to our path). You can then specify that rr uses that by doing `rr replay -d gdb-rr-emacs`

If however we have enabled `gdb-many-windows` and then try and do this we get an error message saying:

> Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!

along with a bunch of junk showing that we definitely did specify `-i=mi`.

This only happens when an error message is displayed at the start of running rr like so:

> rr: Warning: Your CPU frequency governor is 'ondemand'.  rr strongly
>       recommends that you use the 'performance' governor.  Not using the
>       'performance' governor can cause rr to be at least 2x slower
>       on laptops.
>
> ```
> On Fedora-based systems, you can enable the 'performance' governor
> by running the following commands:
>
> $ sudo dnf install kernel-tools
> $ sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
> ```

so you can either disable this warning, (as suggested) or do some code-diving (see below).

So when we do some code-diving we find that this error message comes from a function `gdb--check-interpreter`.

Looking at this function we see it looks like this:

```el
(defun gdb--check-interpreter (filter proc string)
  (unless (zerop (length string))
    (remove-function (process-filter proc) #'gdb--check-interpreter)
    (unless (memq (aref string 0) '(?^ ?~ ?@ ?& ?* ?=))
      ;; Apparently we're not running with -i=mi.
      (let ((msg "Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!"))
        (message msg)
        (setq string (concat (propertize msg 'font-lock-face 'error)
                             "\n" string)))
      ;; Use the old gud-gbd filter, not because it works, but because it
      ;; will properly display GDB's answers rather than hanging waiting for
      ;; answers that aren't coming.
      (set (make-local-variable 'gud-marker-filter) #'gud-gdb-marker-filter)
            )
    (funcall filter proc string)))
```

if we change it to look like this:

```el
(defun gdb--check-interpreter (filter proc string)
  (unless (zerop (length string))
(remove-function (process-filter proc) #'gdb--check-interpreter)
(unless (memq (aref string 0) '(?^ ?~ ?@ ?& ?* ?=))
  ;; Apparently we're not running with -i=mi.
  (let ((msg "Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line! Luckily I don't care!"))
    (message msg)
    (setq string (concat (propertize msg 'font-lock-face 'error)
             "\n" string))))
(funcall filter proc string)))
```

or similar we will then be able to start our rr session in gdb-many-window mode with:

```bash
M-x gdb
rr replay -d gdb-rr-emacs
```